# Sum of two columns by id to one field

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

i need to make sum of two columns by id to one field by that has the same id

for example : i want the Balance which is `income - expenses = balance`

Table Transactions:

```
=========================================================
|  id  | idBudget  |  expenses      ||      income      |
=====+========+===============+=====|=====+========+====|
|   1  |      2    |     10         ||        0         |  
|----+--------+---------------+-----||----+--------+----|
|   2  |      3    |     200        ||        0         |              
|----+--------+---------------+-----||----+--------+----|
|   3  |      2    |     1          ||     100          |  
|----+--------+---------------+-----||----+--------+----|
|   4  |      2    |     0          ||     1000         |              
|----+--------+---------------+-----||----+--------+----|
```

Table Budget:

```
=====================================
|  idBudget        |  Balance       |
=====+========+===============+=====|
|     2            |     1090       |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
|     3            |     -200       |
|----+--------+---------------+-----|
```

i tired to use Triggers but i think i don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE starting_balance AS (SELECT * FROM budget);

DROP TABLE budget;

CREATE VIEW budget AS (
    SELECT
        sb.idBudget,
        sb.balance + SUM(t.income - t.expenses) AS balance
    FROM starting_balance sb
    LEFT JOIN transactions t ON (t.idBudget = sb.idBudget)
    GROUP BY
        sb.idBudget,
        sb.balance
);
```

In other words, use a view instead of a table. You can update the starting balance from time to time (and either delete or flag the transactions you no longer need!), and you could use a materialized view.

Comment: so if i used the view, the table budget will get updated when there's any updates on transaction table?

Comment: No, I mean that you should use a view _instead_ of a table.

Comment: i just found out that my view table doesn't get updated, i mean by creating new budgets, they weren't added to the view table.

Comment: @Disputed It should. If you add a new starting balance to that table, it _should_ show up in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO Budget(SELECT idBudget, SUM(income)-SUM(expenses) as Balance
FROM Transactions GROUP BY idBudget )

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER balance AFTER INSERT  ON Transactions
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Budget(SELECT NEW.idBudget, SUM(NEW.income)-SUM(NEW.expenses) as Balance
    FROM Transactions GROUP BY idBudget )
END;
delimiter ;
```